# Как в javaFX сделать так, что бы окно закрылось через несколько секунд

Tags: java, javafx

Начал переделывать свой проект из Swing в JavaFX и столкнулся с такой вот задачей. У меня (в Свинге), сначала открывался JFrame (читай: окно), потом, спустя 3 секунды окно автоматически закрывалось и вместо него открывалось другое окно. Всё просто! А вот в JavaFX не могу так сделать! 
Кто поможет?

Comment: это splash screen?

Comment: Возможно, javafx.application.Preloader это то что нужно.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Да, это splash screen! Спасибо за наводку, буду двигаться в этом направлении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видно самому придётся отвечать на свой вопрос. Из предложенных вариантов я понял, что моим требованиям соответствует - splash screen (спасибо: Mikhail Vaysman). На просторах и-нэта нашлось много вариантов splash screen'ов, но все они мне показались какими-то громоздкими. Для простой задачи, как моя - это уж слишком! Поэтому, обработав несколько вариантов кода, выбросил всё лишнее и оставил только самое... самое... 
Вот. Может кому и сгодится?!

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    launch(args);
}

// этот метод запускает первое окно на n-секунд
@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

    try {
        // Запускаем заставку
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/splash.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT); // без обрамления
        stage.show();

        PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(3));   // заставка запустится на 3 секунды
        delay.setOnFinished(event -> {
            stage.close();  // закроем окно
            showMainStage();  // откроем другое окно
        });
        delay.play();

    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}

// этот метод запускает основное окно 
private void showMainStage() {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/mainWindow.fxml"));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        stage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Пробуй так. Из минусов: блокируется основной поток.

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = new Button("Button");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```